# Errors while using AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android, qt, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm a beginner to Android app development and I recently installed Android Studio.
When I was trying to run the AVD, this error occurred, This Application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

[image]

How can I resolve this??